# Java date iterator factory, with rules specifying how to calculate the intervals

Tags: java, date, iterator, rules

I am looking for a Java class where I can specify a set of date rules, such as "every 3rd sunday" and "the first occurrence of a monday every second month". I want to be able to get something like an infinite iterator out of it (.next() would return the next date matching the rules set).

I think I'd be able to build it myself - but calendars are a hassle, and it feels like something similar should exist already. I hate being the one to reinvent a crappier wheel.

Is anyone aware of something like this? I have been looking at JODA, and it seems to lay the groundwork for it, but does not appear to give the full functionality I want..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's any readily made iterators for joda-time or Java Calendar API for that matter, however with joda it's so easy that you should just go with it. For example after re-familiarizing myself with joda after a few months pause I made this in about 10 minutes:

```
public class InstantIterator implements Iterator<Instant>,
                                        Iterable<Instant> {

    private Instant current;
    private final Instant original;
    private Duration skip;
    private List<Instant> skipThese;

    public InstantIterator(Instant startFrom, Duration skip) {
        this.current = original = startFrom;
        this.skip = skip;
        skipThese = new Vector<Instant>();
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

    public Instant next() {
        Instant currentNext = current.toInstant();
        current = current.plus(skip);
        while (skipThese.contains(currentNext)) {
            currentNext = current.toInstant();
            current = current.plus(skip);
        }
        return currentNext;
    }

    public void remove() {
        skipThese.add(current.toInstant());
    }

    public Iterator<Instant> iterator() {
        return this;
    }

    public void rewind() {
        current = original.toInstant();
    }

    public void resetRemoved() {
        skipThese.clear();
    }

    public void resetIterator() {
        rewind();
        resetRemoved();
    }
}
```

Joda Time is awesome :-)

Comment: While not important at all, I just want to say that this is the second Iterator I've ever made which supports remove(), usually I've found it to be too cumbersome to support it.

Answer (score 0):

My company has [something very much like you want](http://precisionsoftware.blogspot.com/2009/03/natural-language-net-date-parser.html) but it's for .NET so it probably won't do you any good.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) which is designed for job scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Easy, with *java.time*.

For 3rd Thursday:

```
LocalDate.now().with(                                             // Get today's date, then adjust.
    TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( 3 , DayOfWeek.THURSDAY )  // Define adjuster to move to third Thursday of same month.
)                                                                 // Instantiates another `LocalDate` object (java.time uses immutable objects).
```

## java.time

The troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are now obsolete, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 17 ) ;
```

For any `LocalDate`, you can adjust into the ordinal occurrence of a day-of-week within the same month (ex: third Thursday, 2nd Tuesday, etc.). Specify the day-of-week using [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

To make the adjustment, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementations found in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class.

```
TemporalAdjuster thirdThursdayAdjuster = TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth​( 3 , DayOfWeek.THURSDAY ) ;  // Third-Thursday.
```

Apply that adjuster to any `LocalDate`, producing another `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate thirdThursday = ld.with( thirdThursdayAdjuster ) ;
```

> something like an infinite iterator out of it (.next() would return the next date matching

Simply move from one `LocalDate` to another. You could call `LocalDate::addMonths`. Or if dealing with a month at a time, use the `YearMonth` class.

```
TemporalAdjuster thirdThursdayAdjuster = TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth​( 3 , DayOfWeek.THURSDAY ) ;  // Third-Thursday. 
List<LocalDate> dozenThirdThursdays = new ArrayList<>( 12 ) ;
YearMonth start = YearMonth.of( 2018 , Month.MARCH ) ;
for( int i = 1 ; i <= 12 ; i ++ ) {
    YearMonth ym = start.plusMonths( i ) ;
    LocalDate firstOfMonth = ym.atDay( 1 ) ;
    LocalDate thirdThursday = firstOfMonth.with( thirdThursdayAdjuster ) ;
    dozenThirdThursdays.add( thirdThursday ) ;
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).