# How to get the first date and last date using current month and year on scala

Tags: scala, date, playframework

I would like to get the First date and last date using current month and year on play Scala. I'm trying this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382897/how-to-get-start-and-end-date-of-a-year,) but it's return as empty
Here mentioned that code. What will i do? can any one help me.

```
def sampleDate(year: Int,month: Int) = Action {implicit request =>
 println("---------m&y----------",year,month)
 var endOfMonth = Calendar.getInstance();
 println("---------Month----------", endOfMonth.set(Calendar.MONTH,month))
 println("---------Year----------", endOfMonth.set(Calendar.YEAR,year))
 Ok("")
}
```

Output:

```
(---------m&y----------,2016,11)
(---------Month----------,())
(---------Year----------,())
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this way:

```
val today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()

// create the date/time formatters
val minuteFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm")
val hourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh")
val amPmFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("a")

val currentHour = hourFormat.format(today) enter code here     // 12
val currentMinute = minuteFormat.format(today)  // 29
val amOrPm = amPmFormat.format(today)           // PM
```