# How to get Start Date and End Date of current year in Java?

Tags: java, datetime

I need to get the start and end date of the current year in java? Can anyone help me with how can I perform the same?

Comment: Try using google to search for `get the start and end date of the current year in java` - amazing results, would not believe it.

Comment: well ... I think it's safe to assume the start date will be somewhere around January 1st

Comment: Unless he is Chinese ?

Comment: Under the linked original question use [the answer by Przemek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33866875/5772882). The other answers are outdatred. And remember also to use [the comment by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382897/how-to-get-start-and-end-date-of-a-year#comment74691595_33866875) about specifying desired time zone.