# Java: Iterating through start and end dates, best practice?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

What is the best practice to iterate through a start and end date?

Comment: Best practice is to come up with a solution that works and is readable.  And to stop wittering on about "best practice".

Comment: Jon Skeet´s answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174899/java-joda-time-implement-a-date-range-iterator question may be an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once used a variant of the following [Date Iterator](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-can-i-iterate-through-all-dates-in-a-range).

Not sure if it is a best practice or not, but it was a clear solution and I liked it.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = HashMap.keySet().iterator();
while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(myVeryOwnIterator.next());
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate between certain time units such as every hour between two dates, you could take a look at this obligatory [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) answer: [Java date iterator factory, with rules specifying how to calculate the intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847520/java-date-iterator-factory-with-rules-specifying-how-to-calculate-the-intervals/847597#847597)